# Avoid Aliases in result from FetchXml with linked entities

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I have the following FetchXML:

```
<fetch>
<entity name="list" >
    <attribute name="listname" />
    <attribute name="listid" alias="List" />
    <filter type="and" >
        <condition attribute="listname" operator="eq" value="Test 1" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="listmember" from="listid" to="listid" intersect="true" alias="listmember" >
        <attribute name="entitytype" />
        <attribute name="listmemberid" />
        <attribute name="entityid" />
        <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="entityid" alias="contact" >
            <attribute name="contactid" />
            <attribute name="owneridname" />
            <attribute name="owneridtype" />
            <attribute name="ownerid" />
        </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
</entity>
```

The result looks like this:

```
<resultset morerecords="0" paging-cookie="&lt;cookie page=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;listid lastnull=&quot;1&quot; firstnull=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;/cookie&gt;">
  <result>
    <listname>Test 1</listname>
    <listmember.entitytype formattedvalue="2">2</listmember.entitytype>
    <listmember.listmemberid>{6739D9B9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-000D3A3852A3}</listmember.listmemberid>
    <listmember.entityid type="2">{039FD4C6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-000D3A385A1C}</listmember.entityid>
    <contact.contactid>{039FD4C6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-000D3A385A1C}</contact.contactid>
    <contact.ownerid name="CRM Test" dsc="" type="8" yomi="CRM Test">{5ABA5CBA-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-D472F64781F6}</contact.ownerid>
</result>
</resultset>
```

My issue now is that I have a generic way to retrieve the attributes returned by a FetchXml. But since this one has linked entites the aliases are added to the result, like:

```
<listmember.listmemberid>
```

So my retrieve will throw an error since I am looking for "listmemberid"

Is there a way to avoid having these aliases added to the result? Specially since the attribute names are unique?

Any ideas to get around this issue?

Comment: You get aliases and then it’s value because you are retrieving data from linked entity. Whenever you do that I.e retrieving from linked entity you will have to use aliases, as  far as I know you cannot circumvent it.

Comment: I think you need to update your "generic way to retrieve the attributes". The alias is there to protect you in cases where the attribute names are the same (e.g. "new_name"). I don't think there is a way of removing that. You can take the alias name out, and then i believe it uses the entity schema name. The issue is that if you have multiple links it will append numbers (contact, contact2, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option to override the `alias` of the select column which is working - when you do aggregate function and I tested the below working example.

```
<fetch top="50" aggregate="true" >
  <entity name="account" >
    <attribute name="businesstypecode" alias="test" groupby="true" />
    <link-entity name="contact" from="accountid" to="accountid" link-type="inner" alias="acc" >
      <attribute name="accountrolecode" alias="testing" groupby="true" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Result:

```
test    testing
1       3
1
```

This didn't work. I don't know why, maybe limitation of fetchxml.

```
<fetch top="50" >
  <entity name="contact" >
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="accountid" alias="acct" >
      <attribute name="name" alias="acctNAME" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Result:

```
fullname        acct.name
arun account    arun account
```

Even with the Query Expression, you will get a special datatype called `AliasedValue` to handle this, so this is intended behavior. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.aliasedvalue?view=dynamics-general-ce-9)

Answer (score 1):

You get these aliases and then it’s value because you are retrieving data from linked entity. Whenever you do that I.e retrieving from linked entity you will have to use aliases, as  far as I know you cannot circumvent it.

What I could suggest is if you need data only from ListMember entity and not from List and contact,
Create your fetch based on list member entity such as

```
select * from listmember where listname="Test 1"
```

But as soon as you need data from related entity, that related entity shall be aliased.